# Using Django URL's to send posted information to another page

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I am new to Django, and I was wondering how I could use the URL's (or any other way) to send information from one webpage to another webpage. I tried making a global variable and return the information but it didn't work. In this example, I need to send the posted data for `quote` to the next page when the submit button is pressed.

Here is my model:

```
from django.db import models

class OrderEntry(models.Model):
    quote_num = models.CharField(max_length=50, primary_key=True)
    customer = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    cust_po = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, editable=True)
```

Form:

```
from django import forms

class Details(forms.Form):
    quote_number = forms.CharField(max_length=50, min_length=3)
    customer = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    po_number = forms.CharField(max_length=50, min_length=4)
```

View:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from orders.models import OrderEntry, Items
from orders.forms import Details, ItemDetails

def entry(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = Details(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid:
        customer = request.POST.get('customer')
        quote = request.POST.get('quote_number')
        purchase = request.POST.get('po_number')
        obj_oe = OrderEntry(customer = customer, quote_num = quote,
            cust_po = purchase)
        obj_oe.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/entry/items')
else:
    form = Details(
    initial={'quote_number': 'QS', 'po_number': 'PO-'}
    )
return render(request, 'order.html', {'form': form})

def entry_items(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = ItemDetails(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid:
        # quote = quote value
        a1 = request.POST.get('i1')
        a2 = request.POST.get('i2')
        a3 = request.POST.get('i3')
        a4 = request.POST.get('i4')
        a5 = request.POST.get('i5')
        a6 = request.POST.get('i6')
        a7 = request.POST.get('i7')
        a8 = request.POST.get('i8')
        a9 = request.POST.get('i9')
        a10 = request.POST.get('i10')
        obj_oi = Items(quote_num = quote, item_1 = a1, item_2 = a2, item_3 = a3, item_4 = a4,
            item_5 = a5, item_6 = a6, item_7 = a7, item_8 = a8, item_9 = a9,
            item_10 = a10)
        obj_oi.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/entry')
else:
    form = ItemDetails
return render(request, 'order_items.html', {'form': form})
```

Lastly, urls:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from orders import views_orders

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
url(r'^entry/$', views_orders.entry),
url(r'^entry/items', views_orders.entry_items),
]
```

So how can I get the value for `quote` into a variable in the next page?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('namespace:name', args=(var_to_send,)))
```